# Python 2.7 - NameError: name 'servervpn' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to store a line of text in a file to a variable with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

fo=open("/home/asb/crt/id2tcpvpncom443.ovpn")
for line in fo:
  if line.find('remote')==0:
    vpn=line.split(" ")
    if len(vpn) > 1:
      servervpn=vpn[1] + ":" + vpn[2]
      hostvpn=vpn[1]
      portvpn=vpn[2]
print 'server: '+servervpn
```

And the `/home/asb/crt/id2tcpvpncom443.ovpn` looks like this:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
;remote shellbump.com 887
remote  188.166.179.165 443
#remote 8gag.com 975
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
```

I want the result to be:

```
server: 188.166.179.165:443
```

How should I do this?

**EDIT:**

Actually the `id2tcpvpncom443.ovpn` is much longer than this, here's the complete file I'm trying to read: http://pastebin.com/PNphqXtt

Comment: `if len(vpn) > 1:` probably evaluates to `False`, and `servervpn` never gets defined.

Comment: Did u try my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code slightly modified to make it work

```
#!/usr/bin/python

fo=open("/home/asb/crt/id2tcpvpncom443.ovpn")
for line in fo:
    if line.strip().startswith('remote'): # startswith is a bit more direct here
        vpn=line.split() # split without argument splits at any whitespace
        if len(vpn) > 2: # not necessary but defensive -> good
            servervpn=vpn[1]
            hostvpn=vpn[1]
            portvpn=vpn[2]
            # if you like you can short-circuit here:
            break

print 'server: ' + ':'.join([servervpn, portvpn])
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, actually the `id2tcpvpncom443.ovpn` is much longer than that, I put it in pastebin http://pastebin.com/PNphqXtt can you take a look once again ?

Comment: I'll be happy to, but could you be more specific? I tried on your short test file and it works for me. I'll have a look at your larger file. In the mean time could you try and reproduce the error message as faithfully as possible? checked - it works with either vversion of the file for me.

Comment: Check out this image https://s21.postimg.org/hqu2bd9fr/screenshot_2017_02_19_14_54_44.png

Comment: Ok, first question: did you copy my version of your code faithfully? Does indentation look exactly the same?

Comment: Yes everything looks the same, but it still produces the same error, please try to read the long file I gave you above

Comment: Did already and it works for me. Ok let's do some hitech super-sophisticated debugging. Could you be so kind and insert `print line` right after the `for` statement?

Comment: Yes everything is printed but a new empty line is created in every line https://s10.postimg.org/oirac5q6h/screenshot_2017_02_20_00_34_14.png I hope you still want to help me even thought I replied to you after 9 hours, sorry I went to bed early

Comment: We all must sleep. I can't load the picture you posted; could you try again?

Comment: Ah nevermind it's been solved thanks to your script, I just woke up and made a typo right away, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

I more pythonic way:

```
with open('your_file', 'r') as fp:
    # this is the right way to open a file
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('remote ') and line.count(' ') >= 3:
            _, ip, port = line.split() # split to every word seperator
            print ip, port
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative regex solution.

```
import re 
with open('your_file', 'r') as fp:
    a = fp.read()
    m = re.search(r'^remote\s+([\d.]+)\s+(\d+)', a, re.MULTILINE)
    print("server: {}:{}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2) ))
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, can you take a look at my edited post once again ?

Comment: Sorry, there was some typos. Try now. I hope it's fine.

Comment: I got `NameError: name 're' is not defined` Did you test the file I shared in pastebin ?

Comment: I thought you will understand that you need to add `import re` at the top. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting on a single space character; if your separation is two spaces or a tab, things won't work as expected. Instead, split on (generic) whitespace:

```
vpn=line.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import re

with open("/home/asb/crt/id2tcpvpncom443.ovpn", 'r') as f:
    line = re.findall(r'remote\s*(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\s+\d{3})', f.read())[0]
    print ('server: ' + ':'.join(line.split()))
```

Output:

```
server: 188.166.179.165:443
```